# detecting OK on alert

Tags: javascript

I used this code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function finish()
  {
    alert("Inserted!");
  }
</script>
```

I want when the user clicks on "OK" of alert,it goes to another php page.

- how can I undersatand when user clicks OK?
- and how I can link to another page?In common I use this way:

  ```
  <button type="submit" onclick="window.open('home.php')"> Insert </button>
  ```

  but in alert example there is no button!

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`alert()` is blocking: The browser will stop executing any Javascript code while an `alert()` is being displayed. The next line of code after the `alert()` will only be executed when the alert box is cleared.

Therefore, you don't need to do anything special to tell if an alert has been cleared; just put the rest of your code to run after the `alert()`.

Comment: I guess instead "modal" you want to say "blocking"

Comment: @Prusse - it is also modal, but yes, "blocking" is the specific aspect of it that I was trying to emphasise.

Answer (score 2):

There is no result to `alert`. You  can use `window.location` to redirect.

```
  function finish()
  {
    alert("Inserted!");
    window.location = 'newpage';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can I undersatand when user clicks OK?

`alert()` is blocking, script execution pauses while it is displayed. When the user clicks OK, the script will continue running. Just put whatever other code you want after the alert statement.

> and how I can link to another page?

You can set `location` to a new URL…

```
location = "http://example.com/";
```

… but generally speaking, you would be better off running the function as a click [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#addEventListenerBasic) of a regular link.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect by calling `window.location=URL`.

Alert is modal, it just gives information and then is dismissed. The script will continue executing after the alert message is dismissed.

If you want to just redirect after the user reads the alert message, you could use:

```
function finish() {
  alert("When you click OK you will go to a new page.");
  window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
}
```

On the other hand, Confirm gives the user a question and returns true/false based on the user response. This is probably what you should use instead.

In this case your function could look like this:

```
function finish() {
  var continue = confirm("Finish and go to the next page?");
  if (continue) {
    window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
  }
}
```

With either finish function, just attach it to the button however you want. The most direct way would be like you've done in your question:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="finish()"> Insert </button>
```

Note, though, if your button is in a form and you bind with onclick, the form is actually going to be submitted anyway unless you bind to the submit event and prevent it.